# How class is constructed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the below code in python 3,

```
class Spam(object):
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
  def bar(self):
    print('Am Spam.bar')
```

metaclass for `Spam` is `type` and base class for `Spam` is `object`.

---

My understanding is,

the purpose of base class is to inherit the properties. Metaclass is to construct the given class definition, as shown below,

```
body= \
"""
def __init__(self, name):
  self.name = name
def bar(self):
  print('Am ', self.name)
"""
clsdict = type.__prepare__('type', 'Spam', (object,))
exec(body, globals(), clsdict)
Spam = type('Spam', (object,), clsdict)


s = Spam('xyz')
s.bar()
```

Code is tested [here](https://repl.it/@mohet01/ElderlyCavernousCougar).

---

With the given syntax `def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases)` to use,

Does `__prepare__()` require passing `'type'` as first argument?

Comment: It requires passing the metaclass as the first argument. If you're using metaclass `type`, then that's what you pass.

Comment: @Barmar Without passing `type` as first argument, it works

Comment: Keep it simple - class and objects are pretty obvious. A class is a blueprint of the object. Metaclasses for classes are like classes for objects - a blueprint of creating the class.

Comment: @Vinny This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) explains what

Answer (score 2):

`type.__prepare__` is a bit special, in that it ignores all and any arguments passed to it and returns an empty `dict`.

```
>>> type.__prepare__()
{}
```

That said, you are not calling `__prepare__` correctly. It is called with: the `name` of the class to be created, its `bases` and any keyword arguments the class is being  created with. `__prepare__` is called as `metaclass.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)` Thus,

```
class MyClass(SomeBase, arg="value", metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...
```

will have `__prepare__` called as:

```
MyMeta.__prepare__("MyClass", (SomeBase,), arg="value")
```

However, most user defined meta classes define their `__prepare__` as a `classmethod` meaning the metaclass is implicitly passed. Meaning your `__prepare__` definition can look like:

```
@classmethod
def __prepare__(metaclass, name, bases, **kwargs):
    ...
```

But `__prepare__` is still called in the same way as before. It is through the magic of descriptors that the `metaclass` argument is added.